# Is there a way to get the paste section of this code to cycle down one row at a time each time data is pasted?

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

My aim with this bit of code is to paste the contents of column D into a different Sheet if the contents in column N on the same row within the initial Sheet is = "REDUCE ONLY".
I'm struggling to find a way to paste all the entries into the second Sheet with no blank rows between them.

Currently I'm sorting the initial Sheet so all the REDUCE ONLY entries are in order at the top of the column N so they're ordered correctly in the output sheet but this isn't very robust if I get a different set of values to what's expected in column N. Is there a different way to phrase: 
"cfdSht.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues"

So far I've got:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim rCheck As Range
Dim LRMAIN As Long
Dim cfdSht As Worksheet
Dim mainSht As Worksheet

Set mainSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set cfdSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductSettingNgCfd")

''Set Last Row

LRMAIN = mainSht.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

''Set Range

Set rCheck = mainSht.Range("B2:N" & LRMAIN)

''Copy any value in column D where the value on the same row in column N is "REDUCE ONLY". Paste into second Sheet with starting point adjusted up 1 row.

For Each c In rCheck
    If c.Value = "REDUCE ONLY" Then
        mainSht.Cells(c.Row, 4).Copy
        cfdSht.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next
```

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so please mark it as correct by clicking on the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will close the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
mainSht.Cells(c.Row, 4).Copy
cfdSht.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1)
```

With this

```
cfdSht.Cells(cfdSht.RowsCount, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).value = mainSht.Cells(c.Row, 4).Value
```

The first part will start at the bottom of the sheet then go up to the first occupied cell then move one down to the first unoccupied cell.

I used the direct assign method, because it is less taxing on the process than copy and paste.  As you were looking only for values this will just put the value of the one cell into the other.